# Leaflet markers duplicating, removeLayer problem

Tags: ajax, laravel, leaflet

I have Ajax function in my Laravel project. I'm taking data from db and send them on Leaflet map.
When I have setInterval, markers starts to duplicate. Unfortunately removeLayer can not help me, or I'm ussing it wrong.

This is my code

```
 function callAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/device_new',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {    
                markerLayer.removeLayer(); 
                var markerLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
                var coordinates = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                    if (coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y) {
                        marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
                            .bindPopup("Device: " + coordinates[i].device_type + '<br>' + "Time: " + coordinates[i].datetime)

                        marker.addTo(markerLayer);
                    }
                }

                map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());

            },

        });
        setInterval(callAjax, 3000);
    }
```

Any idea what could be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

`removeLayer(<Layer>)` removes a single given layer from the featureGroup.

You need

```
markerLayer.clearLayers()
```

to remove all layers.

Comment: No matter which one I use, even map layer is removed. Whole div is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
 function callAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/device_new',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {    
                markerLayer.clearLayers();

                var coordinates = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                    if (coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y) {
                        marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
                            .bindPopup("Device: " + coordinates[i].device_type + '<br>' + "Time: " + coordinates[i].datetime)

                        marker.addTo(markerLayer);
                    }
                }

                map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());

            },

        });
        setInterval(callAjax, 3000);
    }


function loadMap() {
            // Where you want to render the map.
            var element = document.getElementById('osm-map');

            // Height has to be set. You can do this in CSS too.
            element.style = 'height:405px;', 'width:500px;';

            // Create Leaflet map on map element.
            map = L.map(element);

            // Add OSM tile leayer to the Leaflet map.
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

            map.pm.addControls({
                position: 'topleft',
            });

//********************** ADD HERE **************    
        var markerLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);  

        }
```

Comment: When Im put var markerLayer outside the function, map is blank.

Comment: Even if I put it outside the function and .addTo(map) write on marker, it shows regulary. But clearLayers() don't work again.

Comment: What do you mean with blank? Completely blank/white or without markers?

Comment: Do you get an error in console? In theorie you have a group `markerLayer` which is added to the map and at the beginn of the "time" loop you clear this group and then you add all markers to the group and so to the map over the group too.

Comment: Completely blank, no markers, no map, just gray background in that div.

Comment: can you share me your code over a link? f.e. jsfiddel.net. It must not working, only that i see the full js code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204331/discussion-between-goran-bl-and-falke-design).